# In R, how can you check if a record in one column matches a value, and if so, alter a record in another column?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have the following data in R:

```
name               coltype     x     y
ADDL_AUTH_AMT      DECIMAL     11    2
BILL_NAME           CHAR       30    0
BIRTH_DATE          DATE       4     0
```

What I want to do is check if the second column has "DECIMAL", and if so, change the value for x to x+1. Here's what I have tried:

```
db2$coltype2 <- ifelse(db2$COLTYPE %in% c('DECIMAL'), db2$LENGTH+1, db2$LENGTH)
```

Basically, if COLTYPE is DECIMAL, take length and add 1 to it. If not, just use the value of length. It created a new column, but with the exact same values and nothing changed at all.

**How can I check if a row in a column is equal to a value/string, and then alter a row in another column?**

Comment: `db2$x <- db2$x + (db2$coltype == 'DECIMAL')`

Comment: @Ryan results in "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, VALUE, value = integer(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 14"

Answer (score 1):

We need to change the column names

```
ifelse(db2$COLTYPE %in% c('DECIMAL'), db2$x+1, db2$x)
```